# Select value with ajax loaded options

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I have a customer object in my scope that has a country and a state (as id). 
Certain countries require the user to select a state. So if one of those countries is selected, the states are loaded into an object and a state dropdown is shown.

```
<select ng-model="customer.country" ng-init="getStatesContentData(customer.country)"
  ng-change="getStatesContentData(customer.country)" ng-options="country.isocode as country.name for country in countries" required>

<select ng-model="customer.state" ng-options="state.id as state.name for state in states[customer.country]">
```

`getStatesContentData(country)` executes an ajax request and puts the states in `$scope.states[country]`

**Now the problem is, if I load the site as a logged in user (= have a given state in my customer object) the default option is displayed and not the state which id is given.**

Following hack offers a solution. This code is executed after the `$scope.states[country]` is filled.

```
if($scope.customer.state){
  $scope.customer.state++;
  $scope.customer.state--;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: try with $scope.apply(). if it will not work create a fiddle.

Comment: I already tried `$scope.apply()` but had no luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

yes try this

```
if($scope.customer.state){
    //$scope.customer.state++;
    //$scope.customer.state--;
    $scope.getStatesContentData($scope.customer.state)
 }
```

Comment: This absolutely doesn't work. As is mentioned the `getStatesContentData(country)` method accepts a country and not a state.

Comment: if the user already then you have his country in your 

you can make it like this


`if($scope.customer.state){
    //$scope.customer.state++;
    //$scope.customer.state--;
    $scope.getStatesContentData($scope.customer.state)
 }`